# Error after Run Ant Target server-setup-seed-deploy-test using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

Tags: oracle11g

my name is Benni.

I asking for help about the my trouble, would you mine to help me ?
After I download FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5 and in the Application Navigator, under the Resources node, right-click build.xml (under bin) and
choose Run Ant Target using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 and select server-setup-seed-deploy-test I got this error :

SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
31 Jan 14 18:34:27 oracle.mds

WARNING: Failed to load WSDL from oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl due to: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl", caused by: java.io.IOException.    : java.io.IOException: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: The file to be loaded oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl does not exist.

WARNING: Failed to load WSDL from oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl due to: Error in getting XML input stream: oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: The file to be loaded oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl does not exist.

WARNING: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
31 Jan 14 18:34:28 oracle.integration.platform.blocks.WLSPlatformConfigurationProvider 
WARNING: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
31 Jan 14 18:34:28 oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.WSDLManager loadWSDL
WARNING: Failed to load WSDL from oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl due to: WSDLException: faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Error reading import of oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/orderbooking/OrderBookingProcessor.wsdl: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl", caused by: java.io.IOException.    : java.io.IOException: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: The file to be loaded oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl does not exist.

Caused by: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: Error in getting XML input stream: file:/C:/Oracle/FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5/11.1.1.6/CompositeServices/OrderBookingComposite/oracle/rules/com/example/globalcompany/ns/orderbookingservice/selectsupplierrule/EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules: C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MetadataManagerImpl.java:288)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:624)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getDocumentAsInputStream(MetadataManagerImpl.java:164)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.getDocumentAsInputStream(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:486)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.initRuleCatalog(OracleRuleEngine.java:867)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.getRuleCatalogs(OracleRuleEngine.java:541)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MetadataManagerImpl.java:284)

31 Jan 14 18:34:29 oracle.bpel.services.common.ServicesLogger __logException
SEVERE: <.> Error while loading the rule catalog.
The rule catalog cannot be loaded.
Check the underlying exception and correct the error. If the error persists, contact Oracle Support Services.

C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
Error while loading the rule catalog.
The rule catalog cannot be loaded.
Check the underlying exception and correct the error. If the error persists, contact Oracle Support Services.

C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.getRuleCatalogs(OracleRuleEngine.java:544)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.getRuleCatalog(OracleRuleEngine.java:604)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.fabric.ComponentModelValidator.validate(ComponentModelValidator.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at oracle.soa.scac.rules.DecisionComponentValidator.validate(DecisionComponentValidator.java:118)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.validateComponentTypeServicesReferences(ValidateComposite.java:1051)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.doValidation0(ValidateComposite.java:502)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.doValidation(ValidateComposite.java:481)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.run0(ValidateComposite.java:206)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.run(ValidateComposite.java:187)
    at oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite.main(ValidateComposite.java:179)
Caused by: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: Error in getting XML input stream: file:/C:/Oracle/FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5/11.1.1.6/CompositeServices/OrderBookingComposite/oracle/rules/com/example/globalcompany/ns/orderbookingservice/selectsupplierrule/EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules: C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MetadataManagerImpl.java:288)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:624)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getDocumentAsInputStream(MetadataManagerImpl.java:164)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.getDocumentAsInputStream(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:486)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.initRuleCatalog(OracleRuleEngine.java:867)
    at oracle.bpel.services.rules.rpi.oracle2.OracleRuleEngine.getRuleCatalogs(OracleRuleEngine.java:541)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Oracle\FusionOrderDemo_R1PS5\11.1.1.6\CompositeServices\OrderBookingComposite\oracle\rules\com\example\globalcompany\ns\orderbookingservice\selectsupplierrule\EvaluatePreferredSupplierRule.rules (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at oracle.fabric.common.metadata.MetadataManagerImpl.getInputStreamFromAbsoluteURL(MetadataManagerImpl.java:284)

Caused by: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.LocalizedWSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Failed to read wsdl file at: "oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl", caused by: java.io.IOException.    : java.io.IOException: oracle.mds.exception.MDSException: MDS-00054: The file to be loaded oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl does not exist.
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:382)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseImport(WSDLReaderImpl.java:937)

Comment: have you investigated the "FileNotFoundException: .\config\jps-config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)" or the "MDSException: MDS-00054: The file to be loaded oramds:/apps/FusionOrderDemoShared/services/oracle/fodemo/storefront/store/service/common/serviceinterface/StoreFrontService.wsdl does not exist"?  There appear to be several errors which you need to investigate before anyone else is likely to be able to help.

Comment: I already investigating that but still not found the solution. The conclusion about all the errors above is my server-setup-seed-deploy-test error so it is not success. So would you mind to help me ?

Comment: I added my comment as I was reviewing your question.  I have no recent oracle experience - so you will need to hope someone else chips in with suggestions.

Comment: I have made some modifications to my question to make it simple to analyze.